# How to remove redundant information for an openStreetsMap Mapnik

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

I'm using Mapnik openstreetsmap for having an offline map available in my application. The thing is that the map is huge making my apk reach 70MB which is very large. Is there a way to remove some information layers from the map? keeping just the road for example?

Answer (score 0):

When talking about an "offline map" then I guess you are refering to [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles)? Of course [tiles are large](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_Disk_Usage). There are two possible ways:

- Use [vector maps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles) instead of pre-rendered tiles, as done by [OsmAnd](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OsmAnd), [Navit](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Navit) and other applications
- [Render your own tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) with a reduced [stylesheet](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Stylesheet)